# The existence of the derivative of a function at a point implies the continuity of the function at that point.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

In preparation for my first course in complex variables I am trying to read Brown and Churchill, Complex Variables, 8th edition.  On page 59 they give the following justification for the statement in the title.

Assume $f'(z_0)$ exists then:

$$\lim_{z \to z_0} [f(z) - f(z_0)] = \lim_{z \to z_0} \left[ \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0} \right] \cdot \lim_{z \to z_0} [z - z_0] = f'(z_0) \cdot 0 = 0$$

and the result follows.

I understand everything except the first equation. It looks like they applied a theorem about limits of quotients without regard to the hypothesis of that theorem?  I have not been in a calculus class for 30 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f'(z_{0})$ exists. Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{z\to z_{0}}[f(z)-f(z_{0})]&=\lim_{z\to z_{0}}\left[\frac{f(z)-f(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}\cdot (z-z_{0})\right]\\
&=\lim_{z\to z_{0}}\left[\frac{f(z)-f(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}\right]\cdot\lim_{z\to z_{0}}[z-z_{0}]\\
&=f'(z_{0})\cdot0\\
&=0.
\end{aligned}
$$

In the first equality, we are just multiplying $f(z)-f(z_{0})$ by $1$.

In the second equality, qe are using the product rule for limits, which we are allowed to do since each of the individual limits exists.

In the third equality, we have evaluated each of the respective limits in order to conclude that our initial limit is $0$, which is what is needed to establish continuity at $z_{0}$.

Comment: My concern is that (z - z_0)/(z - z_0) is NOT equal to 1 for ALL z in C.  I am looking closely at the definition of limit now and it seems that we need not be concerned with the case z = z_0.  Right?

Comment: That's right. As long as $z\not=z_{0}$, the fraction IS equal to $1$. If $z=z_{0}$, then the fraction is $0/0$, which is undefined, but, as you pointed out, when taking a limit we are only interested in values of $z$ near $z_{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

The book applies a theorem about a limit of **product**  functions which states that if $\lim_{z \to z_0} g(x)$ and $\lim_{z \to z_0} h(x)$ exist then the limit $\lim_{z \to z_0} g(x)h(x)$ exists and we have

$$ \lim_{z \to z_0} g(x)h(x) = \lim_{z \to z_0} g(x) \lim_{z \to z_0} h(x). $$

In your case, $g(z) = \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0}$ and $h(z) = z - z_0$. The limit $\lim_{z \to z_0} g(x)$ exists by hypothesis that $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z_0$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the proof should not start with just plopping down the term $\lim_{z \to z_0} [f(z) - f(z_0)].$ Why? Because we don't know the limit exists at the beginning! Rather, I'd write the proof this way: For $z\ne z_0,$

$$ f(z) - f(z_0)=  \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0} \cdot (z - z_0).$$

As $z\to z_0,$ the first factor on the right $\to f'(z_0),$ and the second factor $\to 0.$ From the product rule for limits, $\lim_{z\to z_0} [f(z) - f(z_0)] = f'(z_0)\cdot 0 = 0.$